# JPQL / SQL query: where like '%' include null values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, jpql

I have a simple JPQL query. (But this applies also to an sql query..)

```
FROM DomainObj d where d.field1 like 'TEST%' and d.field2 like '%';
```

If the DB contains the following row:

1) field1 -> 'TEST'; field2 -> null

the query return nothing!

If the DB contains the following values:

2) filed1 -> 'TEST'; field2 -> ''

the query return the row!

How can I include also null values while searching for like '%' keeping the query as simple as possible (avoiding and/or clause?)

I'm implementing searching funcionality of an entity in the db.. and I also search by many fields at the same time..

Thank you
Marco

Comment: `null` generally indicates the absence of a value so it makes no sense for `LIKE '%'` to return those rows.

Comment: I tend to think of it more as "unknown"

Comment: is your code is complete? or did you simplified to give us an example? `and d.field2 like '%'` is irelevant because any value on field2 will match (except null) as you mention

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't directly use nulls in equality tests, because null is un-equal to everything, including itself. That's why there's the `is null` test, e.g:

```
select null = null -> null
select null <> null -> null
select 1 = null -> null
select 1 <> null -> null
select 1 + null -> null
```

essentially null is contagious, and will nullify anything it's compared to, or added in to.

So yes, you'll have to do

```
SELECT ... WHERE somefield LIKE '%...%' or somefield IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
...
and IFNULL(d.field2, '') like '%'
```

Comment: I've do some test and I think this is best solution for me.. but I can't find this function. Il try to search!

Comment: My mistake, NVL() is an Oracle function.  I have fixed my answer so that the IFNULL() function is used.  This is the MySQL equivilent.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
where ...
and (field2 = '' or field2 is null)
```

Note that the condition `field2 like '%'` is nonsensical because it matches any text except null. If you added `or field2 is mull` to it you would match everything, so logically you should just *remove* the condition on field2

Comment: Don't know why nobody voted this up. This just saved me from making an illogical and stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IS NULL`:

```
where d.field1 like 'TEST%' OR d.field2 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM DomainObj d where (d.field1 like 'TEST%' or d.field1 IS NULL) and (d.field2 like '%' or d.field2 IS NULL)
```